# If there are two differentiable functions $G$ and $H$ s.t $G(a)=H(a)$ and $G'(x)\geq H'(x)\Rightarrow G(x)\geq H(x),x\geq a$

Tags: real-analysis

[image: intuition]$G:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $H:E\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $D,E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $[a,\infty)\subseteq D\cap E$

I take a Point $x$ in the interval $(a,\infty)$, I know that $G'(x)\geq H'(x)$. Now I want to Show $G(x)\geq H(x)$

Assume $G(x)<H(x)$ what would that imply and how can I invoke a contradiction?

And if $G$ and $H$ are complex valued I would have to consider the absolute value.

Comment: You need to assume the domain of the two functions is connected, otherwise this will be false.

Comment: okay I added it now - can you give me a hint for the solution?

Comment: Try letting $f(x)=G(x)-H(x)$ and apply Lagrange's mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Apply the MVT (mean value theorem) to $G'(x)-H'(x)\geq 0$ to show that $G(x)-H(x)$ is monotonically increasing for $x \geq a$ (if you haven't already shown that $F'(x) \geq 0$ implies that $F$ is monotonically increasing).

Comment: Gaahh, you beat my comment by 11 sec :)

Comment: Oops... sorry ^^

Comment: Thank you so much $g'(x)\geq h'(x) \Rightarrow g'(x) - h'(x)\geq 0 \Rightarrow (x>a\Rightarrow g(x)-h(x)\geq g(a)-h(a)>0)\Rightarrow g(x)>h(a)$